# How can I add data into Firebase Web 9.0.0?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I was using Firebase over year ago and I am confused on how to do basic CRUD in newest Firebase.

My Todo item that I want to add to Firebase db is:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import firebase from '../utils/firebase'

export default function Form() {
const [title, setTitle] = useState('')

const handleChange = (e) => {
    setTitle(e.target.value)
}

const createTodo = () => {
    const todoRef = firebase.database().ref('Todo')
    const todo = {
        title,
        complete: false
    };

    todoRef.push(todo)
}

return (
    <div>
        <input type="text" onChange={handleChange} value={title}/>
        <button onClick={createTodo}>Add Todo</button>
    </div>
    )
}
```

My firebase.js in utils is:

```
import firebase from 'firebase/compat/app';

const firebaseConfig = {
apiKey: "AIzaSyDyfhIiB32tReM7E66wFR8oD0mMC3LKZWM",
authDomain: "nutriapp-b77ee.firebaseapp.com",
projectId: "nutriapp-b77ee",
storageBucket: "nutriapp-b77ee.appspot.com",
messagingSenderId: "717648627918",
appId: "1:717648627918:web:b382565fc790dd1495a89f",
measurementId: "G-W3H2K8NGNJ"
};

firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig)

export default firebase;
```

Please help, thanks

Comment: What's not working as intended? It does seem like you are using compat libraries and the namespaced syntax.

Comment: TypeError: _utils_firebase__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__.default.database is not a function

Comment: Just noticed you have not imported database. Please add this in utils/firebase: `import 'firebase/compat/database';`

Comment: Added, error does not occur but database is not having new entry

Comment: Try adding this: `todoRef.push(todo).then(() -> console.log("data added")).catch((e) => console.log(e))`

Comment: @Dharmaraj [2021-09-06T14:14:58.866Z]  @firebase/database: FIREBASE WARNING: Firebase error. Please ensure that you spelled the name of your Firebase correctly (https://nutriapp-b77ee-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/)